# Український аналог Vocabulary-4000

Tags: resource-request

Для моєї англійської виявився корисним словник «Vocabulary 4000: The 4000 Words Essential for an Educated Vocabulary» Джефа Колбі (Jeff Kolby, 
ISBN: 1889057568, ISBN13: 9781889057569, published by Nova Press: 1997, 2000, 2009, 2012, 2014, 2016). Там присутня значна частина з розповсюджених (але не сленгових) слів, що мені не відомі, але часто зустрічаються в художній літературі, якісній публіцистиці та блогах тощо.

Чи існує такий український словник? Кілька тисяч слів, що не є неологізмами або спеціальними термінами, та при цьому з (ґрунтовним) зазіханням на сучасність, освіченість та автохтонність. Умовна "непозбувна бентега" :) Словник для людини, що раніше читала якісну російську літературу та переходить на українську. Зрозуміло, що процес поступовий, але словник може його сильно прискорити.

Якщо такого словника немає, то що можна було б взяти за основу? Бо досвід з Vocabulary-4000 демонструє, що власноруч слова додаються (набагато) повільніше, аніж того б хотілось. Знову ж якість.

Comment: @P.Vovk, а та й [список online sources](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/8): (а) поки що не містить жодного словника **такого типу**; (б) взагалі-то містить лише безкоштовні посилання (а автор, можливо, хоче *купити* — і це має збільшувати scope — хоча не факт).

Comment: якщо ви збираєтеся **читати українську літературу** (для англійської теж підійде) , один із варіантів вирішення вашої проблеми: купуєте електронну книгу з вбудованими словниками (я користуюсь pocketbook зі словниками lingvo) і під час читання можете переглянути переклад будь-якого слова. Це дуже зручно і дозволяє вам враховувати контекст уживання слова. Подібне програмне забезпечення можна знайти і для ПК або планшета та все ж краще поберегти свій зір.

Comment: Передивилась, дякую, є цікаві ресурси про які раніше було невідомо. Буду ще дивитись. Так багато користуюсь УМІФ та інколи СУМ. Але саме такого словника/ресурсу поки що не знайшла. Такого, цінність якого була б у тому що в одному місті компактно зібрана сучасна лексика що має претензію на освідченість. Самостійно з класичних/сучасних художніх творів я це буду складати для себе наприклад 3 роки, а якщо словник вже є (чи хоча б якась база для нього) то буде набагато швидше. Є різниця.

Comment: Скоріш за все візьму за основу корпус частотні словники українського корпусу текстів. Та чекатиму на словник моєї мрії)

Comment: Ось це мабуть те що я шукала: http://vsiknygy.net.ua/neformat/48228/

Comment: Я не певен, що подібний словник існує. Що стосується корпусів, можна скористатися сайтом tatoeba - він містить більше 50,000 українських речень. Як варіант, щоб не блукати наосліп - для англійських речень є тег List 907, що об'єднує відносно прості речення, можна йти по цьому англійському тегу і дивитися українські переклади. [Посилання](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=&from=eng&to=ukr&orphans=no&unapproved=no&user=&tags=List+907&list=&has_audio=&trans_filter=limit&trans_to=ukr&trans_link=direct&trans_user=&trans_orphan=&trans_unapproved=&trans_has_audio=&sort=words).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Онлайн-словники:

- [Частотні онлайн-словники на порталі Mova.info](http://www.mova.info/Page.aspx?l1=57) (Вікіпедія, стаття "[Частотний словник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)")
- [Непийвода Н. Практичний російсько-український словник. Найуживаніші слова і вислови. — К., 2000 (6000 слів)](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Nepyivoda_Natalia/Praktychnyi_ros-ukr_slovnyk_naiuzhyvanishi_slova_i_vyslovy.htm) - вказаний у списку [uk.wictionary.org](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2#.D0.A7.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.96_.D1.82.D0.B0_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.83.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.88.D0.BE.D1.97_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8).

Мене зацікавили такі паперові словники (нажаль не знайшов в інтернеті):

- Тлумачний словник-мінімум української мови К., Довіра, 2006 ISBN 966-507-160-2 [Словники України] [близько 9 000 слів] (також з uk.wictionary.org)
- Бук С. 3 000 найчастотніших слів розмовно-побутового стилю сучасної української мови / Наук. ред. Ф. С. Бацевич.— Львів: ЛНУ імені Івана Франка, 2006.— 180 с. (Вікіпедія, стаття "[Частотний словник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)").

---

Anna Avina додає свої знахідки (з [цього списку](http://vsiknygy.net.ua/neformat/48228)):

- Береза Т. Гарна мова – одним словом: словник вишуканої української мови / Т.  Береза. – Львів: Апріорі, 2015. – 420 с.
- Береза Т. Слова, що нас збагачують: словник вишуканої української мови / Т. Береза. Львів: Апріорі, 2016. – 400 с.

Comment: @Artemix Здається що я шукала ось ці дві книжки:

Береза Т. Гарна мова – одним словом: словник вишуканої української мови / Т. Береза. – Львів : Апріорі, 2015. – 420 с.
Береза Т. Слова, що нас збагачують: словник вишуканої української мови / Т. Береза. Львів : Апріорі, 2016. – 400 с.

Здається у них адекватна лексика але як на мене занадто розтягнуте викладання матеріалу. Подивимось)